# How to update and replace part of old data

Tags: r

I want to merge the df OldData and NewData.
In this case, Nov-2015 and Dec 2015 are present in both df.
Since NewData is the most accurate update available, I want to update the value of Nov-2015 and Dec 2015 using the value in df NewData and of course adding the records of Jan-2016 and Feb-2016 as well.

Can anyone help?

```
OldData
      Month Value
1  Jan-2015     3
2  Feb-2015    76
3  Mar-2015    31
4  Apr-2015    45
5  May-2015    99
6  Jun-2015    95
7  Jul-2015    18
8  Aug-2015    97
9  Sep-2015    61
10 Oct-2015     7
11 Nov-2015    42
12 Dec-2015    32

NewData
      Month Value
1  Nov-2015    88
2  Dec-2015    45
3  Jan-2016    32
4  Feb-2016    11
```

Here is the output I want:

```
JoinData
      Month Value
1  Jan-2015     3
2  Feb-2015    76
3  Mar-2015    31
4  Apr-2015    45
5  May-2015    99
6  Jun-2015    95
7  Jul-2015    18
8  Aug-2015    97
9  Sep-2015    61
10 Oct-2015     7
11 Nov-2015    88
12 Dec-2015    45
13 Jan-2016    32
14 Feb-2016    11
```

Thanks for @akrun, the problem is solved, and the following code works smoothly!!

> rbindlist(list(OldData, NewData))[!duplicated(Month, fromLast=TRUE)]

Update: Now, let's upgrade our problem little bit.
suppose our OldData and NewData have another column called "Type".
How do we merge/update it this time?

`> OldData
     Month Type Value
1  2015-01    A     3
2  2015-02    A    76
3  2015-03    A    31
4  2015-04    A    45
5  2015-05    A    99
6  2015-06    A    95
7  2015-07    A    18
8  2015-08    A    97
9  2015-09    A    61
10 2015-10    A     7
11 2015-11    B    42
12 2015-12    C    32
13 2015-12    D    77`

`> NewData
    Month Type Value
1 2015-11    A    88
2 2015-12    C    45
3 2015-12    D    22
4 2016-01    A    32
5 2016-02    A    11`

The JoinData will suppose to update all value from NewData ass following:

`> JoinData
     Month Type Value
1  2015-01    A     3
2  2015-02    A    76
3  2015-03    A    31
4  2015-04    A    45
5  2015-05    A    99
6  2015-06    A    95
7  2015-07    A    18
8  2015-08    A    97
9  2015-09    A    61
10 2015-10    A     7
11 2015-11    B    42
12 2015-11    A    88   (originally not included, added from the NewData)
12 2015-12    C    45   (Updated the value by NewData)
13 2015-12    D    22   (Updated the value by NewData)
14 2016-01    A    32   (newly added from NewData)
15 2016-02    A    11   (newly added from NewData)`

Thanks for @akrun: I have got the solution here for the second question as well.
Thanks for the help for everyone here!
Here is the answer:

d1 <- merge(OldData, NewData, by = c("Month","Type"), all = TRUE);d2 <- transform(d1, Value.x= ifelse(!is.na(Value.y), Value.y, Value.x))[-4];d2[!duplicated(d2[1:2], fromLast=TRUE),]

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's best if you show us what you've done. First, look at the `merge` function. Please make an attempt using this function yourself and post where you get up to.

Comment: `rbind(NewData, OldData)` and then use `duplicated` to throw out the old record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table` (similar approach as @thelatemail mentioned in the comments)

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(OldData, NewData))[!duplicated(Month, fromLast=TRUE)]
```

Or

```
rbindlist(list(OldData, NewData))[,if(.N >1) .SD[.N] else .SD, Month]
```

Comment: however, let's i have another column call "Type", can we using !duplicated it using both rbind and duplicated?

Comment: @atsang01 - You might be better off using `?match` or `?merge` logic then.

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail . let me work a bit on match and merge and will post the answer here once I figured out the multi condition update.

Comment: @atsang01 Please let me know if you need help on this (in that case, updating the post with a new data would be better)

Comment: Hi @akrun, I have just updated my question little bit above. Still working on the solution. I was trying to use merge function as following: merge(OldData, NewData, by = c("Month","Type"), all = TRUE), however, it didn't give me the output that I want. Sorry for the dumb question, I am new to R. Thanks

Comment: @atsang01 Try `d1 <- merge(OldData, NewData, by = c("Month","Type"), all = TRUE);d2 <- transform(d1, Value.x= ifelse(!is.na(Value.y), Value.y, Value.x))[-4];d2[!duplicated(d2[1:2], fromLast=TRUE),]`

Comment: @akrun U r super!! This is so awesome...Now I can update the data by saving tons of time. Thanks again!

Comment: @akrun, the code itself is perfect, however, since I have a big data set, over 30 millions rows of data, so using the transform function and group by 9 variables seems using all available memory or resources. Is there any solution for it? I keep getting the error: cannot allocate vector of size xxx Mb.

Comment: @atsang01 Can you try with `dplyr` i.e. `library(dplyr);full_join(OldData, NewData, by = c("Month", "Type")) %>% mutate(Value.x= ifelse(!is.na(Value.y), Value.y, Value.x)) %>% select(-Value.y) %>% filter(!duplicated(.[1:2], fromLast=TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I will check if the full_join function function well in big data set. I will post the result once it successfully export.